# Why does querying HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF return the status-line of an HTTP response?

Tags: internet-explorer, wininet

Calling:

```
l_hrResult = l_spWinINetHTTPInfo->QueryInfo( HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, l_pszBuffer,  &l_nSize, &l_nFlags, 0 );
```

Yields:

```
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
X-Jive-Request-Id: 72403b70-1131-11e5-92d1-0050568b475f
X-Jive-Flow-Id: 72403b71-1131-11e5-92d1-0050568b475f
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Expires: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 18:32:57 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
X-JSL: D=84282 t=1434133977254214
Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 18:32:57 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding

"
```

This is on Windows 7 x64, IE 11.

I would very much expect the first line to NOT be returned in a request for headers.  It's hackable presumably in that any content found before the first crlf that doesn't contain a field/value delimiter : could be discarded - but that's a hack...

Am I using this wrong?

Comment: Hard to say exactly what's going on with just a single line of code.  (We've no idea what the value of _&l_nFlags_ is, for example.)  I don't have access to the SDK at the moment, however, I note that the ref page discussing the supported flags (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385351(v=vs.85).aspx) does not include "IONIC_" as part of the constant token it seems you're trying to use.  Are you sure you're using the right constants?  Also, the response may be attempting to correspond to RFC 2616 (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html).  Sadly, the ref page doesn't say.

Comment: l_nFlags = 0;The 'IONIC' was a typo from a temporary override in the last example I was trying to resolve the issue - apologies.

Comment: (The IONIC_ definition was just a quick test to try other values than the default headers define...)

Comment: The current tutorial (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385373(v=vs.85).aspx) appears to take a slightly different approach.  Perhaps that will lead to the results you're looking for.

Comment: The first half of that example is what I'm already doing.  The query custom part is only for querying a known header.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not using it wrong.

The first line of the response (The "Status-Line") is indeed a part of the headers, it precedes the name/value paired Header fields.